Using the Stripe API, how to retreive a payment intent from a connected account?
I'm using stripe to build an application that uses connected accounts. I need to retrieve the paymentIntent that was used for a purchase associated with a given connected account. I'm able to create the paymentIntent using the syntax listed as the first example here: https://docs.stripe.com/connect/authentication, but when I try to use the same syntax to retrieve a payment intent I get the following error:
Received unknown parameter: stripe_account
This is the code I'm using to retrieve the payment intent:
$payment_intent = $stripe->paymentIntents->retrieve(
        $payment_intent_id,
        ['stripe_account' => $connected_account_id]
    );

Is it possible to retrieve a paymentIntent from a connected account and if so, how do I do it if not using the same syntax as creating the patmentIntent?
I'm using PHP and prefer to do this server-side, but I'm open to using JS on the client if necessary. Thank you.

You need an array for the body and one for the headers (stripe_account)
$payment_intent = $stripe->paymentIntents->retrieve(
    $payment_intent_id,
    [], 
    ['stripe_account' => $connected_account_id]
);

If you go back to see the syntax used to create a paymentIntent, you'll find that it does that as well, but it's admittedly not as obvious for GET requests.

This worked; thank you!
